# Excel formula not entering

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

Am trying to make a formula in excel to search with any unique values.
For example, if i want to search with the id to get the passport or vice versa.
But  i cant enter the below formula, no errors or anything i just cant enter the formula.

`IFS(LEN(K1)=10, XLOOKUP(K1, D:D, C:C), (LEN(K1)=11, XLOOKUP(K1, C:C, D:D)`

I tried writing the LEN function in a different cell then taking thr TRUE, FALSE value but still the same thing is happening

I would appreciate your guys solutions for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: No error despite the unbalanced parentheses, are you sure? For reference, 1 `)` is missing right after `LEN(K1) = 11` (unless you remove the `(` right before it); another `)` is missing at the very end of your formula.

Comment: Use nested `XLOOKUP()`. No need `IFS()` function. Try `=XLOOKUP(K1, D:D, C:C,XLOOKUP(K1, C:C,D:D))`.

Comment: Did yo put a `=` in front of the formula? It is missing in the question at least.